# Geckofx18 ignores permissions.sqlite

Tags: vb.net, system.data.sqlite, geckofx

I have a vb.Net(4.0) application which uses geckofx to display websites.

It uses System.Data.Sqlite to create permission.sqlite files to prevent pictures from loading on sites. Now I inherited this application from another developer, and it had the .Net 2.0 version of the System.Data.Sqlite file (1.0.66.0), which I recently upgraded to the 4.0 (1.0.96.0) version.

After this change the hiding mechanism stopped working, all of the pictures are loaded now, causing severe performance issues.

Is it possible that geckofx stops processing the permissions file because of this? The geckofx18 dll is a fairly old version (2013-09-06), and maybe it is unable to process permission files generated with the newer dll?

Can someone confirm this?